# Scan local network to detect windows/mac/linux computers with iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4, network-programming, nsnetservice

I'm trying to figure how to perform some networking tasks using Objective C on the iPhone. I'd like to enumerate all network devices on my local, home network. Also, I'd like to be able to ping individual devices.

Does anyone know how and what tools/libraries I can use to achieve this and other networking tasks? I've checked the iPhone library and found solutions for devices that use Bonjour. I'd like to be able discover and ping devices that don't use Bonjour.

Comment: You can try making http requests to local ip addresses using ASIHTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get somewhere with Windows networking (SMB), but most services use Zeroconf (what Apple calls Bonjour).